# How to convert a date string from "dd-MMM-yy" to "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, cultureinfo, date-parsing

I need to compare two date format strings:

**dateString** in "dd-MMM-yy" format

with

**referenceDateString** in "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" format respectively.

For that, I need to convert the **dateString** = "dd-MMM-yy" to "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt".

However, Got an error while trying to do that:

> "Error: string was not recognized as a valid datetime".

The C# code I used given below.

```
string dateString = "19-Dec-14";
string AsofDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Edit 1:**

In the actual code the **dateString** obtaining after reading a csv file which is supplied as "19-Dec-14", that's why it's in the string format.

Please help, am pretty new to C#. Thanks.

Comment: For parsing you will need `"dd-MMM-yy"` as you specified in your question. Does your format `"M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` *remotely*  matches your `dateString` `"19-Dec-14"` ?

Comment: Later use the format `"M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` in `ToString` on parsed `DateTime` object.

Comment: You should not worry about comparing *strings*, but just compare the `DateTime` objects. This means you only have to worry about parsing, and to parse you need to use the format that matches the string (see Habib's comment).

Comment: imho there is enough information on the internet about formatting. The amount of questions still is overwhelming. People google is your friend.

Comment: To be precise, I need to convert the 19-Dec-14 to 12/19/2014 12:00:00 AM ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Habib already gave the answer on his comments, I try to add it as an answer;

From [`DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly**.

In your case, clearly they don't. First, you need to parse your `string` to `DateTime` with *proper* format (which is `dd-MMM-yy` with an english-based culture), then you can get the string represention of your `DateTime` with *specific* format.

```
string s = "19-Dec-14";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump();
    // Result will be 12/19/2014 12:00:00 AM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but in order to parse that date you have on the first line, you would use something like this:

```
DateTime AsofDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd-MMM-yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note a couple things here:  I've changed the data type of `AsofDate` from `string` to `DateTime` because that's what `DateTime.ParseExact` returns.  Also, I've modified the custom format string to match the format of the string you are trying to parse as a date (`"19-Dec-14"`).